# A comilation error of a forName method

Tags: java, class

Why does the following snippet of code gives a compile-time error?  The compiler shows "Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException".

```
 public class ClassObjectTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Class s=Class.forName("java.lang.Thread");
        }
    }
```

Comment: java.lang.* should be loaded by default, correct me if I am wrong, why do you want to load it again?

Comment: @TheLostMing I feel so sad. There must be something going wrong in my computer.

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara - He is not loading it again.. He is referring to the class `Thread` using its *complete name*. which is fine. The class which is  *already loaded* will be returned

Comment: @ZhuLi "have you tried turning it off and on again"?

Comment: @Mena  No, it doesn't work.

Comment: @ZhuLi I was just joking. This doesn't seem to be reproducible, unless you're using some modded JRE...

Comment: Could you correct your example to handle thrown exceptions? Or is this real code?

Comment: Are you saying you get a runtime error *"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.Thread"*? Or a compiler error *"unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"*?

Comment: @Radiodef It was a compile-time error and I have found the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: When you come here with an error, please just post the error message. Making us guess is not helpful and generally gets your question put on hold because we don't have enough information to answer.

Comment: @ZhuLi - when you say "it doesn't work", people assume that you mean it compiles correctly but fails at runtime.  If you are trying to say that you have a compilation error, you should say "there is a compilation error" ... not "it doesn't work".  Generally speaking, people cannot read your mind.  If you describe your problem in a vague or inaccurate way, your Questions are likely to get downvoted and closed.

Comment: @StephenC  Thank you for pointing out my mistakes. I will try not to make any similar mistakes in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like This

```
public class ClassDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {
        Class cls = Class.forName("ClassDemo");

        // returns the ClassLoader object
        ClassLoader cLoader = cls.getClassLoader();

        /* returns the Class object associated with the class or interface 
        with the given string name, using the given classloader. */
        Class cls2 = Class.forName("java.lang.Thread", true, cLoader);       

        // returns the name of the class
        System.out.println("Class = " + cls.getName());
        System.out.println("Class = " + cls2.getName()); 
     }
     catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: You are right. It is wrong because I did not add try and catch. I thought that exception handling is something not necessary all the time, but now it seems that my thought was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Radiodef The Dirrence Is Try Catch

Comment: @DanyialShahidAli (Put that in your answer...)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are mixing something. Your piece of code cannot be compiled because the method `Class.forName(className)` **might** throw an exception `ClassNotFoundException` if for the passed class name no class can be found in the current class path.

If you compile your code you get this compilation error

```
error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

which means:

- either you put the method call into an try-catch block

  ```
  try {
      Class s = Class.forName("java.lang.Thread");
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      // do your exception handling here
  }
  ```
- or you declare the method (in your example the `main`method) to throw this exception

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
      Class s = Class.forName("java.lang.Thread");
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class ClassObjectTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class<?> s = Class.forName("java.lang.Thread");

            System.out.println(s.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but you have to sorround with try catch. The ouput generates "java.lang.Thread".

I hope this was helpful for you.